# AWS Lambda - mounting RAM disk

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

AWS Lambda is limited to storing 512 MB of ephemeral data in /tmp

For a particular use case I need to process more than this - up to several GB in a few hundred files.

I could mount an EFS drive but that then requires mucking about with VPC and NAT Gateway which I am trying to avoid.

Am using various executables (via layers) on these files so I can't just load files into memory and process.

Is there a way of setting up a ramdisk in Lambda (I understand that I would have to provision and pay for a large amount of memory).

I have tried executing

```
mount -t tmpfs -o size=2G myramdisk /tmp/ramdisk
```

but receive error `mount: command not found`

Comment: Haven't tried it, but I assume if you use a docker-based Lambda, you can install all the tools you like and manage the RAM as you please.

Comment: I don't think Lambda is a suitable solution here.

Comment: @jellycsc this particular use case is perfect for the idea FaaS in many ways (infrequent and unpredictable load and need many instances running at same time) but yes it is pushing the boundaries of the Lambda tech

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of 24 March 2022, Lambda supports a configurable ephemeral storage up to `10 GB` of space.

Reference: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/