# Is AWS Lambda's "ephemeral storage" for /tmp RAM or not?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

It's also been asked previously whether its possible to mount a RAM disk on a Lambda when using docker images.
See [AWS Lambda - mounting RAM disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70683878/aws-lambda-mounting-ram-disk)

The answer that it's now possible to use 10GB of /tmp storage is useful.
See https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/aws-lambda-now-supports-up-to-10-gb-ephemeral-storage/

However, what's not clear from either the SO answers or from any of the AWS documentation I've found so far is whether this "ephemeral storage" (/tmp) is a RAM disk - or more importantly as quick as a RAM disk? Is it actually ephemeral because it's in RAM or is it something else entirely? If so, what is it?

The documentation here says "disk space" in 1MB increments but again doesn't give any hint as to what that storage is (RAM, SSD, whatever) or any of the performance characteristics of it.
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtime-environment.html

Comment: it is ephemeral because the files remain in the tmp folder up until the whole lambda execution environment is shut down. See documentation about Lambda environment lifecycle: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-runtime-environment.html

Comment: Thanks. Useful link but doesn't answer the question. Updated the question to refer to it.

Comment: why do you care about the type of storage?

Comment: I care about the performance - before I spend a bunch of time seeing if doing ram-based storage actually makes a performance difference, I'd like to know what I'm comparing against - if it's RAM based anyway, then I won't even bother doing the comparison.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it's local SSD storage, just from the performance I've seen. I can't find any documentation to prove that though. It is definitely NOT a ramdisk.

Comment: You might enjoy reading this series of articles about how AWS Lambda operates: [Operating Lambda: Performance optimization – Part 1 | AWS Compute Blog](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/operating-lambda-performance-optimization-part-1/)